# No highlighting for [objective-c++]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Even though it's less popular than any of the related languages [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), it still deserves proper highlighting.

Could a mod please add a highlighting-hint `lang-c` to [objective-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c%2b%2b)?